# Handle foreign key constraints during multi table insertions with one transaction

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to insert data into multiple tables with foreign key constraints in a single transaction using Python and psycopg2. But, during execution of child table insertions, I get insert or update on table "ref_default" violates foreign key constraint. How should I handle this or multiple table insertions in single transaction not possible?

Comment: Insert the rows in the correct order, with the dependent rows last.

Comment: Define your Foreign keys as [DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) or at the transaction level [Set Constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set-constraints.html).